# Counting the number of undirected 2-regular labeled graphs for small n

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm trying to count the number of undirected 2-regular labeled graphs with $n$ vertices for $n = 6, 7, 8, 9$. My counting logic seems to be off since I can't get to the exact values given [here](https://oeis.org/A001205). My approach is as follows:

Such 2-regular graphs consist of several cycles, so I try to count, for every partition of $n$ into parts of size $\geq 3$, the number of ways of constructing cycles with lengths as in the parts. For example, for $n = 6$, one can have a cycle of length 6 or two of length 3, and I get
$$
\frac{6!}{6 \cdot 2} + \frac{{6 \choose 3} \cdot 3! \cdot 3!}{3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2^3} = 70
$$
where to avoid overcounting, in the first term I divide by $6$ to account for rotations of the same $6$-cycle, and by $2$ because each cycle has two possible directions (clockwise/anti-clockwise). I repeat the same logic in the case with $2$ triangles, where in this case I divide by $2^2$, two directions for each triangle, and an extra $2$ due to the symmetry of the partitions (i.e the cycles $(123)(456)$ and $(456)(123)$ are the same graph).

There must be something wrong in this logic because for $n = 7, 8, 9$, my results are off, for example for $n = 8$:
$$
\frac{8!}{8 \cdot 2} + \frac{{8 \choose 5} \cdot 5! \cdot 3!}{5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2^3} + \frac{{8 \choose 4} \cdot 4! \cdot 4!}{4 \cdot 4 \cdot 2^3} = 3171 \neq 3507
$$

Can anyone help me see the flaw in my counting? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're dividing by a third two in the second summand, which should be removed to fix your calculation. It makes sense to have this many twos in the third summand, because the sets of size 4 are indistinguishable, but not in the second summand.

Comment: This was it, thank you. You should post this as an answer.